When and Why to use API Gateway (Ocelot) (frontend and backend) , Load Balancer, Identification Service, Service Registry, oAuth
I'm building a .NET microservices based application and I'm trying to understand the authentication/authorization mechanism involved in a Industry standard app. I understand that API gateway sits between the client (react native) and server and Identification service uses jwt tokens to add, retrieve, remove authentication/authorization for user data. I'm using Ocelot API gateway to achieve that and I see there's also load balancing feature, Jwt Authentication feature, availaible in ocelot itself. Why will I need to include a load balancer separately ? And if I can use jwt authentication in API gateway why will i need to implement jwt tokens in Identification service? I'm overwhelmed with all these buzz words and not sure how the flow works? From client to API Gateway to Microservices and all the way back again? Any clarity will be appreciated, Thank you. Forgive me If I'm not making sense here.
I'm trying to learn from this repo: https://github.com/aelassas/microservices
Any good resources/repo to learn microservices better will be helpful. I'm looking for low cost microservice.
